# System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code in simple code

Tags: development

I got this exception in very easy code and I have running with elevated privileges around it.

```
 private void ChangeVersioningOnDocumentLibrary(SPListItem item, SPItemEventProperties properties, SPSite site)
        {
            string sitename = item[MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_TEXT_TITLE_NAME].ToString();
            string prefix = item[MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_TEXT_TITLE_NAME].ToString().Substring(0, 2);
            bool isConfirmed = item.TaxonomyFieldValueIsGivenValue(properties.AfterProperties, MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_MEETINGSTATUS_NAME, MeetingsCommon.Constants.TERMVALUE_MEETINGSTATUS_CONFIRMED, 1033);
            bool isPublished = item.TaxonomyFieldValueIsGivenValue(properties.AfterProperties, MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_MEETINGSTATUS_NAME, MeetingsCommon.Constants.TERMVALUE_MEETINGSTATUS_PUBLISHED, 1033);

            if (isConfirmed)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(prefix + "/" + sitename))
                    {

                            if (web.Exists)
                            {
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                SPList agendaPoints = web.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTS_NAME);
                                agendaPoints.EnableModeration = true;
                                agendaPoints.DraftVersionVisibility = DraftVisibilityType.Author;
                                agendaPoints.Update();
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            }

                    }
                });
            }
            if (isPublished)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(prefix + "/" + sitename))
                    {                    
                        if (web.Exists)
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPList agendaPoints = web.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTS_NAME);
                            agendaPoints.EnableModeration = false;
                            agendaPoints.DraftVersionVisibility = DraftVisibilityType.Author;
                            agendaPoints.Update();
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }                    
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the web from the current context of SPSite, thus not actually elevating privledges. Open the site again within the delegate to elevate priviledges.

For example:

```
var id = site.ID;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite newSite = new SPSite(id))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = newSite.OpenWeb(prefix + "/" + sitename))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```